# jssor error when no images

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, jssor

I'm trying to use Jssor Slider with knockoutjs and I get the following error in my console when my imageArray is empty:

GET http://localhost:50741/website/null 404 (Not Found)

I am using this code, to dinamically generate the images in the view,

```html
<div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 720px; height: 480px; overflow: hidden;">
        <div data-bind="foreach: userPictures()">
            <img u="image" data-bind="attr: { src: pictureUrl}" />
            <img u="thumb" data-bind="attr: { src: pictureThumbnail }, click: selectImage" />
        </div>
    </div>
<!--...-->
</div>
```

My suspicions are in the "thumbnavigator" as well as I can see a broken image when I show the entire control with no images loaded.

```html
<div u="thumbnavigator" class="jssort07" style="width: 720px; height: 100px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
        <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin Begin -->
        <div u="slides" style="cursor: default;">
            <div u="prototype" class="p">
                <div u="thumbnailtemplate" class="i"></div>
                <div class="o"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
     <!-- ... -->
  </div>
```

I was reading the documentation finding no issues related with this behaviour.

Please, can someone give me a clue about how to avoid this error?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are passing 'null' when creating your url string,
http://localhost:50741/website/null

Which is probably due to your empty imageArray object.  I would suggest checking for nulls where you are building these urls.